# Parse String in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, parsing

in a PostgreSQL database I have a table with a cell that contains working hours per day and its value is something like this:

```
---
Fri:
- '8'
- '9'
- '10'
- '11'
- '12'
- '13'
- '14'
- '15'
- '16'
- '17'
Mon:
- '8'
- '9'
... etc ...
Wed:
- '8'
- '9'
- '10'
- '11'
- '12'
- '13'
- '14'
- '15'
- '16'
- '17'
```

How can I read or put it in another table like this:

| dow | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08:00:00 | 18:00:00 |
| 2 | 08:00:00 | 18:00:00 |
| 3 | 08:00:00 | 18:00:00 |

Where dow stands for day of week, for example 1 for monday, 2 for tuesday, etc..

Code Sample to create the starting table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  wh text
);

INSERT INTO test (wh ) VALUES ('---
Fri:
- ''8''
- ''9''
- ''10''
- ''11''
- ''12''
- ''13''
- ''14''
- ''15''
- ''16''
- ''17''
Mon:
- ''8''
- ''9''
- ''10''
- ''11''
- ''12''
- ''13''
- ''14''
- ''15''
- ''16''
- ''17''
Sat:
- ''8''
- ''9''
- ''10''
- ''11''
- ''12''
- ''13''
Thu:
- ''8''
- ''9''
- ''10''
- ''11''
- ''12''
- ''13''
- ''14''
- ''15''
- ''16''
- ''17''
Tue:
- ''8''
- ''9''
- ''10''
- ''11''
- ''12''
- ''13''
- ''14''
- ''15''
- ''16''
- ''17''
Wed:
- ''8''
- ''9''
- ''10''
- ''11''
- ''12''
- ''13''
- ''14''
- ''15''
- ''16''
- ''17''');
```

Code sample to create the destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE working_hours
(
  dow integer NOT NULL,
  hour_start time ,
  hour_end time,
  CONSTRAINT pk_dow_working_hours PRIMARY KEY (dow)
);

INSERT INTO working_hours (dow, hour_start, hour_end, customer_user ) VALUES (1, '08:00:00', '18:00:00');
INSERT INTO working_hours (dow, hour_start, hour_end, customer_user ) VALUES (2, '08:00:00', '18:00:00');
INSERT INTO working_hours (dow, hour_start, hour_end, customer_user ) VALUES (3, '08:00:00', '18:00:00');
INSERT INTO working_hours (dow, hour_start, hour_end, customer_user ) VALUES (4, '08:00:00', '18:00:00');
INSERT INTO working_hours (dow, hour_start, hour_end, customer_user ) VALUES (5, '08:00:00', '18:00:00');
INSERT INTO working_hours (dow, hour_start, hour_end, customer_user ) VALUES (6, '08:00:00', '14:00:00');
```

Comment: Could you provide the real table schema?

Comment: Add sample datas at the same time

Comment: How can I provide you a sample schema? Do you need the DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of regex magic the text can be transformed into a json with arrays.

Then it's just a matter of processing the json.

> ```
> select 
>   case l2.WeekDay
>   when 'Mon' then 1
>   when 'Tue' then 2
>   when 'Wed' then 3
>   when 'Thu' then 4
>   when 'Fri' then 5
>   when 'Sat' then 6
>   when 'Sun' then 7
>   end as DayOfWeek
> , (l2.HourStart||':00')::time as TimeStart
> , (l2.HourEnd||':00')::time as TimeEnd
> from test
> cross join lateral (
>   select ('['||
>    regexp_replace(
>     regexp_replace(
>      regexp_replace(wh, 
>       '[^\w:]*([\w:]+)[^\w:-]*','"\1",','g')
>     , '"(\w+):",', '{"day":"\1","hours":[','g')
>     , '"(,[{])|",$', '"]}\1','g')
>     ||']')::json as whjs
> ) l1
> cross join lateral (
>   select 
>     value->>'day' as WeekDay
>   , value->'hours'->>0  as HourStart
>   , value->'hours'->>-1  as HourEnd
>   from json_array_elements(l1.whjs)
> ) l2
> ```

| dayofweek | timestart | timeend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 08:00:00 | 17:00:00 |
| 1 | 08:00:00 | 17:00:00 |
| 6 | 08:00:00 | 13:00:00 |
| 4 | 08:00:00 | 17:00:00 |
| 2 | 08:00:00 | 17:00:00 |
| 3 | 08:00:00 | 17:00:00 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d9178fd436a31fa0ebf3588ca00fa023)*

Comment: A thousand thanks LukStorms, you are a true Postgres and Regex black belt!

Comment: Thx, and glad that it works. But not many times I've seen a question where they deliver the data is such a weird format.

Comment: It's from the database of OTRS, a service desk solution. They have a table names sysconfig_modified for generic configuration end they store them in a weird format.

Comment: Ah, well at least it's a generated format then, which makes it predictable.

Comment: I'm still studing what you have done, because I need to do something similar with other configurations, this time for vacation days configuration.

Comment: This is an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d8a205fe2bb8e0b372b74ce5c0d0f98b

Comment: I added another question here with the new text to parse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71017528/postgres-parse-vacation-days-test-to-table