# Postgres parse vacation days test to table

Tags: regex, postgresql, parsing

I have a table that store configurations and I need to use them in a query.
The starting table has its value stored as this text:

```
---
'1':
  '1': New Year's Day
  '6': Epiphany
'11':
  '1': All the Saints
'12':
  '24': Christmas Eve
  '25': First Christmas Day
  '26': Second Christmas Day
  '31': New Year's Eve
'5':
  '1': International Workers' Day
'8':
  '15': Mid-August
```

In the second row, for example, I have the month, end in the third row, with a two space indentation, I have the number of the day with its description separated with a colon.

I want to have it in a table like this one:

| id | description | month | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Year's Day | 1 | 1 |

I put an [example in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e6fdb4e093b6730f10c58430c2d97b55).

Comment: This is a horrible format to store a configuration. It might be easy to read for a human, but it's not really easily parseable by a computer. Do you have a chance to change the format of the configuration? e.g. JSON instead of "structured text with indention"?

Comment: No, this is a configuration stored in the database by OTRS. They store different type of configuration in the same table with their specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More dark regex sorcery to transform text data into a json format.
So that the data can be extracted via json methods.

> ```
> INSERT INTO holidays (holiday,description)
> select 
>   make_date(2018, l2.Month, l2.Day) as holiday
> , l2.Name as description
> from test
> cross join lateral (
>   select 
>   regexp_replace(
>    regexp_replace(
>     regexp_replace(
>      regexp_replace(wh, 
>       '^\W+(\d+)\W+(\w.*)$',' {"day":"\1","name":"\2"},','gm')
>     , '^''(\d+)'':', '{"month":"\1","days":[','gm')
>     , '\},(\s*)(?=\{"month"|$)', '}\1]},','g')
>     , '^.*?(\{.*\}).*$', '[\1]')::json as whjs
> ) l1
> cross join lateral (
>   select 
>     (mjs.value->>'month')::int as Month
>   , (djs.value->>'day'):: int as Day
>   , djs.value->>'name' as Name
>   from json_array_elements(l1.whjs) mjs
>   cross join lateral json_array_elements(mjs.value->'days') djs
> ) l2
> ```
>
> ```
> 9 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from holidays;
> ```

> | id | description | holiday |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | New Year's Day | 2018-01-01 |
> | 2 | Epiphany | 2018-01-06 |
> | 3 | All the Saints | 2018-11-01 |
> | 4 | Christmas Eve | 2018-12-24 |
> | 5 | First Christmas Day | 2018-12-25 |
> | 6 | Second Christmas Day | 2018-12-26 |
> | 7 | New Year's Eve | 2018-12-31 |
> | 8 | International Workers' Day | 2018-05-01 |
> | 9 | Mid-August | 2018-08-15 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9ddcc8bd19c79f1822218d8f12896d82)*

Comment: LukStorms, you are the best! I succeded to create the json, but I was stuck on the next step... Thanks a lot!